# Unable to load the application while using it with Webpack and Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

My initial page will be rendered from the webpack-dev-server and upon accepting the credentials, my application will be loaded. I am unable to run the application but facing this error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

[My folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9h2K.png)

It is showing error in Html page

[This is error on html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7iFq.png)

This is my webpack server code

```
devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "./dist"),
        compress: true,
        port: 3443,
        before: function(app){
            app.use(proxy(['/api', '/login', '/logout'], {
                    target: 'https://' + dest + 'log/',
                    changeOrigin: true,
                    secure: true,
                    onProxyReq: function (proxyReq, req, res) {

                        //console.log(req.url);
                        if (req.url === '/login') {
                            token = "";
                        }
                        if (token) {
                            proxyReq.setHeader('token', token);
                        }
                    },
                    onProxyRes: function (proxyRes, req, res) {
                        if (proxyRes.statusCode == '403') {
                            proxyRes.headers['location'] = 'http://localhost:3443/login';
                        } else {
                            var _locHeader = proxyRes.headers['location'];
                            if (_locHeader && _locHeader.indexOf(dest) > -1) {
                                proxyRes.headers['location'] = 'http://localhost:3443/';
                            }
                            var proxyCookie = proxyRes.headers["set-cookie"];
                            if (proxyCookie) {
                                cookies = proxyCookie;
                                setToken();
                            }
                        }

                    },
                    cookieDomainRewrite: true
                }))
        },
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
```

Comment: Show your full code.

Comment: I have added the code. Please check it @ Edric